# Docker Compose injecting linked containers in v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In v1 of Docker Compose, the `/etc/hosts` file is updated with linked containers.  E.g.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  redis redis_1 c381c79fb9c2 romantic_yonath
172.17.0.3  48d2ed7033a1
```

However, in v2, this is done via DNS, so there are no entries anymore.  I could use the hosts table to bootstrap a load balancer; very useful when used in conjunction with the `scale` command.

Are there any methods to inject these during container creation?

Comment: Built in DNS will do round robin load balancing. Would that be good enough for what you need or do you need something different?

Comment: I don't believe the DNS does round-robin.  I've created an example here:

https://github.com/joedborg/docker-compose-scaling that I think proves this?

Comment: I was going based on their [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/#/discovering-containers-on-the-same-service-or-stack)

Comment: Yes, I did some more reading and saw that you need to create a network alias within the compose file.  I've committed it, if you want to see.

Comment: Is it still not doing round robin?

Comment: It is, but you have to restart the http container once scaled application; not nice and I need to understand why.

Comment: That doesn't seem right, will play around with your example in a little bit. First one to figure out the answer gets an upvote?

Comment: Deal!  Or post it as the answer and I'll mark it as such.  It's just figuring out whether it's Nginx or the container's link to the network configuration that's the issue.

Comment: I figured this out (sort of). Not sure if the answer solves your problem, but step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx blog has this post on [Using DNS for Service Discovery with NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/).

> NGINX caches the DNS records until the next restart or configuration reload, ignoring the records’ TTL values.

Explains what you were seeing, that after restarting the container, you are able to route to new nodes.

The section *Setting the Domain Name in a Variable* has an example of a workaround for caching on startup.

```
resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=10s;

server {
    location / {
        set $backend_servers backends.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_servers:8080;
    }
}
```

> When you use a variable to specify the domain name in the proxy_pass directive, NGINX re‑resolves the domain name when its TTL expires.

[This discussion](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22652) suggests `127.0.0.11` will be the IP of the resolver inside the container.

---

I used this configuration locally to confirm DNS changes are reflected after scaling, and it seems to work

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s;

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        set $application_servers application;
        proxy_pass http://$application_servers:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome find.  I'll update the example to see if I can get it to work too.