# Connect nginx on host with wsgi unicorn inside docker container

Tags: sockets, nginx, docker, unicorn

Starting to dockerize my Rails application I am facing following problem:

My idea was to have every web application with their Wsgi and dependencies running in an extra docker container and the database also ruiing in seperate containers while using docker-compose to set it up.

Outside the containers Nginx is routing traffic then depending on the domain to the specific container via unix sockets.(Didn't want nginx in a container to reduce the complexity and avoid having multiple nginx running in multiple containers to maintain multiple webapps).

Before starting with docker my wsgi and nginx got connected via unix sockets. But after dockerizing this is not working anymore. Only connecting them with ports works now which I would like to avoid.

Is there anyway way to connect Nginx on the host via unix sockets with the WSGI inside a container? If not what is best practice here?

My approach was to use shared volumes as location for the socket file but nginx cant access the socket created by the wsgi unicorn:
Socket created by unicorn:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov 14 14:53 unicorn.sock=
```

Nginx error:

```
*2 connect() to unix:/ruby-webapps/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

Nginx sites-avaible/myapp:

```
upstream myapp {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/ruby-webapps/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
...
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name myapp.de www.myapp.de;

    root /ruby-webapps/myapp;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @MyApp;

    location @MyApp {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        #proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For https;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }   
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version:'2'
 services:
  postgresmyapp: 
    image: postgres
    env_file: .env    
  myapp:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    command: supervisord -c /myapp/unicorn_supervisord.conf 
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" 
    links:
      - postgreslberg
```

config/unicorn.rb:

```
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
working_directory app_dir

rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64
#listen(3000, backlog: 64) 

stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

Comment: Why don't you want them to connect over ports?

Comment: Because the port open like that is also visible from outside the vps. Could set an iptables rule to avoid that or may just open the port at the docker image but simple sockets would be the easiest way

Comment: Container ports aren't open to the world. Take a look at the explanation [here](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/networking-your-docker-containers-using-docker0-bridge/). It's a fairly recent article and the diagrams are helpful in understanding how some of the docker networking options work.

Comment: with my current setting the port gets also open to the public ip. checked it with nmap. would be my next try to just open the port of the container. but what I wanted to know if there is solution with sockets!

Comment: If you take out `ports: - "3000:3000"`, the port won't be open to the world, but you'll still be able to access the container by it's IP address. Then, if you also containerize Nginx config, you can use the build in DNS to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262935/docker-compose-injecting-linked-containers-in-v2/40310616) and you don't have to worry about container IP addresses.